# How to setup VSCode launch.json for Xdebug version 3.0?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am building Laravel project now. Few days ago, I've reinstalled OS (Windows 10) and rebuild all development environment. Problem is updated version of Xdebug.

Debugging backend with version 2 of Xdebug worked well, but I have downloaded dll file which set with Xdebug v3 from xdebug.org/wizard, and according guide (something like I did before). But I cannot debug anymore.

Here is my launch.json file (old version)

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

And it seems there are some features updated from v2.

[image]

Something like above image.
I tried all cases I can but cannot found solution.. Anybody can help me? Any advice is appreciate. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IDE:**
As the upgrade guide (https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide) shows, the first thing that has changed is the port number the IDE's should listen on for connections. This you have highlighted, but make sure you change it to `9003` in the json config file. This should be the only change you have to do in your IDE.

**Next - Config of Xdebug:**
There is this new setting in Xdebug: `xdebug.mode` (https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#mode). Its default value is `develop` and you have to change it (explicitly set it to `debug`) in order to put Xdebug in debug mode (you have to alter `php.ini` for this). Please see documentation for further details.

**UPDATE:**
As @LazyOne correctly suggested in the comments section, if you'd like to keep port 9000, you can skip modifying this in VS Code and instead set the port back to 9000 in the Xdebug settings: https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug#client_port

This being said, the default port number was altered for a reason: https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1848. You might want to adopt the new port number.

Comment: *"This you have highlighted, but make sure you change it to 9003 in the json config file."* OR configure Xdebug to keep using 9000 (that was working just fine before).

Comment: Thanks for relpy guys.
In fact, I tried reinstall vscode and php debugger extension. 
yes, Zoli Szabo is right. 
php ini file setting:

[XDebug] 
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.1-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll

something like above.
and port number should be 9003 in launch.json file.
Now, it work well. 
Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by deleting the cache using artisan command:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

I don't know how this command solved the problem but I noticed that when I change the port to 9003 I still get error on port 9000 ! I think laravel has cached the port !